# Youtube upload with uploadify,pluplad and co

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, uploadify, plupload

I'm using the `youtube_it` gem for managing youtube video in my app

After uploading, youtube make a redirection to a callback with the video id etc...

Uploadify and Plupload (flash) work great for uploading, but make me crazy with the callback.

The redirection (302) is considered as an error and display nothing more.
And without the callback, I can't process the video in database without youtube's video ID

I have tried some options (debug, error events) and I was not able to get the 302 url

With ruby `net/http` the 302 url is returned, there is some magic with flash ?

Here a sample log of plupload.

```
uploader.bind('Error', function(up, err) {
  console.log("Error code: " + err.code);
  console.log("Error message: " + err.message);
  console.log("Error details: " + err.details);
});

Error code: -300
Error message: IO error.
Error details: Error #2038
```

but here instead of 302 I have -300 ? o_o (but this is a 302, video is correctly uploaded on youtube and available)

I don't think it's a plupload or uploadify issue, because I have the same problem with both

Comment: Intersting question. So how do you handle the call back? I am sure using jQuery somehow you can get the data you need even with 302. Can you put some example code in please? of jsfiddle.

Comment: The idea is to get the 302 URL then parsing youtube params and make an ajax request on the callback action from the uploader events (success or error)

Comment: Could you not use onComplete in jquery.ajax, and when 302 run your callback?

Comment: The uploaders are only flash (we can't use ajax upload on youtube) and the events (uploadify or plupload) trigger an IOerror 302 without any other details

Comment: Oh .. so you would have to handle the 302 inside the flash. It has not much todo with uploadigy,pluplaod or much of the client then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, this is not possible. I will look to make a proxy upload on the application server (and activate html5 upload, yeah !)

Comment: a solution might do ajax uploads on youtube: http://cmlenz.github.com/jquery-iframe-transport/ (not tested)